# Dynamic name for org-capture template file

Tags: org-capture, variables

I am new to org-mode (and to Emacs in general) and am trying to set up org-capture.  I would like to define a todo capture item whose template is located in the file `~/.emacs.d/org-templates/todo.tmpl`.  I have tried with

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") 'org-capture)

(setq org-directory "~/org/")
(setq org-default-notes-file (concat org-directory "notes.org"))
(setq org-todo-template (concat user-emacs-directory "org-templates/todo.tmpl"))


(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("t"
         "Todo list item"
         entry
         (file+headline org-default-notes-file "Tasks")
         (file org-todo-template)
        )))
```

I get the error:

```
Wrong type argument: stringp, org-todo-template
```

if I replace the line

```lisp
         (file org-todo-template)
```

with

```lisp
         (file "~/.emacs.d/org-templates/todo.tmpl")
```

then it works, and I do not understand why.

For reference, the content of the file `~/.emacs.d/org-templates/todo.tmpl` is

```
* TODO %^{Description}
  %i
  %a
  - %?
  :LOGBOOK:
  CREATED: %U
  :END:
```

Comment: This is a FAQ, although finding the duplicates is not easy if you don't know the answer already: search for `backquote`.

Comment: @NickD: Yes, this did solve my problem. I searched for all sort of things, but being new to Emacs, I did not exactly now what to search for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      `(("t"
         "Todo list item"
         entry
         (file+headline org-default-notes-file "Tasks")
         (file ,org-todo-template)
        )))
```

The backquote quotes the list but allows the `,` to interpolate the value of the variable `org-todo-template`.